# MongoID Query with Regex and escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, mongodb, mongoid

I want to know if it is necessary to escape regex in query calls with rails/mongoID ?

This is my current query:

```
@model.where(nice_id_string: /#{params[:nice_id_string]}/i)
```

I am now unsure if it is not secure enough, because of the regex.

Should i use this code below or does MongoID escape automatically query calls?

```
@model.where(nice_id_string: /#{Regexp.escape(params[:nice_id_string])}/i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you should escape the input. Consider `params[:nice_id_string]` being `.*`, your current query would be:

```
@model.where(nice_id_string: /.*/i)
```

whereas your second would be:

```
@model.where(nice_id_string: /\.\*/i)
```

Those do very different things, one of which you probably don't want. Someone with a sufficiently bad attitude could probably slip some catastrophic backtracking through your current version and I'm not sure what MongoDB/V8's regex engine will do with that.